# search button not work with me

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, user-interface

```
public Boolean load() {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pre = null;
    Boolean isexist = false;
    try {
        con = DBManager.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM  contacts WHERE mobile=?";
        pre = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pre.setString(1, this.mobile);
        ResultSet result = pre.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
          isexist = true;
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        if (pre != null) {
            try {
                pre.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return isexist;
} 

// and in actionListner  `
Contacts  objj=new Contacts(this.mobile.getText());  
if (objj.load())
{
    this.name.setText("njkn");
    this.mobile.setText("jbnlj");
    this.address.setText("jnl");
    this.email.setText("knkl");
} else 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," error message");
}
```

I created 4 text fields in `JFrame` and I want when user put the mobile num  then click on search button - display other information (name, email, address) but the it is display

Comment: Review your formatting a bit, you commented part of the code which is kinda confusing, and then you wrote the same sentence 4 times.

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) { }` change that to `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` Then see [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the mobile number to the load function as argument, otherwise you can't use it as a parameter for your search.

You need to somehow get the returned values back, either via return or with fields or smt.

You can use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) blocks for any autocloseable, like Connection or PreparedStatement.

I added more comments in the code.

```
// I use hashmap as a return value, the hashmap contains the values from the db
public static HashMap<String, String> load(String mobile) { // You need to pass the number you're looking for
    String sql = "SELECT email, name, address FROM people WHERE mobile=?"; // You only need to return the columns you need
    try (
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(LOCATION);
            PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) { // try with ressources so that the connection and preparedstatement close automatically at the end

        pre.setString(1, mobile); // enter the passed mobile variable in the query
        ResultSet result = pre.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            // You need to return the values from the db somehow
            HashMap<String, String> information = new HashMap<>();
            information.put("email", result.getString("email")); // Get the value in the "email" column and store it with the "email" key
            information.put("address", result.getString("address")); // Get the value in the "address" column and store it under "address" key
            information.put("name", result.getString("name")); // Get the value in the "name" column and store it under "name" key
            return information;

            // You don't need to check if the values exist. If they don't exist it will just return null and you can check that when you call
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null; // return null if the values don't exist
}

// Sample method to build GUI
// I just used this to test everything was working, if you already have a GIU you don't need it
public void GUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JLabel label = new JLabel("enter mobile number and click search");
    JTextField name = new JTextField("name");
    JTextField mobile = new JTextField("mobile");
    JTextField address = new JTextField("address");
    JTextField email = new JTextField("email");
    JButton button = new JButton("Search");
    button.addActionListener(e -> {
        try { // try in case the method returns null
            HashMap<String, String> information = load(mobile.getText());
            // set the textfields with the returned values
            email.setText(information.get("email"));
            address.setText(information.get("address"));
            name.setText(information.get("name"));
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) { // catch the exception for when the entered number was invalid
            label.setText("Invalid number"); // set error message
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(label);
    contentPane.add(mobile);
    contentPane.add(name);
    contentPane.add(email);
    contentPane.add(address);
    contentPane.add(button);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```